# Visual Studio 2017 stop working correctly after remove installer

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

this week I try start new Asp.net core with razor project but intellisense not working in cshtml files so after searches and try different solutions I repair visual studio from external HDD and after that start working happily and all features work correctly but after I disconnect external HDD intellisense stop working on cshtml files again so I connect it again and restart VS and again all thing do correctly.

Now I need know why after installation visual studio again need installer and how can I solve this problem because I don't have enough space on my HDD to copy installer on it.

PS: before I start Asp.net core project I have problem many problem like UE4 can't find VS2017 path and I can't find reason and solve it but after know that VS try load something from installer path I test UE4 and that problem solved as well as intellisense at cshtml.

Edit: When my extrnal HDD DC, this message appear:

[[image: Diagnosticshub.packaging.dll Not Found at ..\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ and ..\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\X86]1]

Comment: Delete the `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, does Intellisense work?

Comment: No, and it's not depends on project or solution because if I create new project it's not different and intellisense not work in cshtml. I think when VS starting, try read something from installer path and when that read action failed, intellisense in cshtml and some other features stop working.

Comment: Any update about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually**, when you use VS IDE, it has nothing to do with vs installer program. Unless you add other workloads, update, or repair.

I think you have installed the Installer program on the extra HDD and install the VS IDE on your local disk.

The right startup program is under `xxx\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` in my side.

You can check this path and in my side, I remove the whole Installer folder, I can use the whole VS IDE without any errors.

So I guess whether you have installed **Download cache** on the extra HDD.

[image]

If you are not this situation, you can ignore it:

**VS IDE** will loads the the download package cache from time to time because the cache contains the default project template, Intelliense or related componment caches. So you have to make sure that the path of **Download cache** is under your local disk rather than the extra **HDD**.

**Suggestion**

You have to install such folder **Download cache** on your local disk.

**1)** To resolve this issue, you have to reinstall VS IDE and when you finish uninstalling VS IDE, start to reinstall it, remember to select the path of the local disk for the **Download cache**.

**2)** This suggestion might have some instability and you could choose to use it:

**a)** You have to recreate a folder called like `D:\Microsoft\VisualStudio` on your local disk and then copied the content from the extra HDD into the new one.

**Note**: if you install the cache under `A:\VisualStudio\Packages` under the extra HDD, you have to copy the whole files from the `A:\VisualStudio` into `D:\Microsoft\VisualStudio` and you should copy all files in the upper level of the folder to the local disk.

**b)** And then open Registry Editor and enter `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup`

**c)** create a new string value called **CachePath** and then set its value to

`D:\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages`

[image]

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late response, I read your answer and I think you accept me some how. my installer and IDE both in my local drive (partition C) and cache is on my external HDD because in tool tip it say cache only use for update or modify VS not use for every time that IDE run so I use external drive to save about 10GB on my local.

Comment: Please see [this official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/set-defaults-for-enterprise-deployments?view=vs-2019#registry-keys). The caches store the workload of vs ide and when you use VS IDE, it loads related tool and maybe also the related Intellisense. So you must make sure that it in your local disk. When you connect with the extra HDD, add the key `CachePath` and then set its path to the packages folder under extra SSH, did it work? Or you should try something to copy the packages from extra HDD into the local, and then add `CachePath` to the local folder.

Comment: Thanks, Copy cache and set registry path works, but my main problem not solved because I don't have enough space and make other question, I have VS 2017 and 2019 and both of them have different cache, which one should I set on registry? Now I set to 2019 (It was set before this maybe by default), is it correct? and other question, if when I unchecked keep download when I install it, every time VS run it download components?

Comment: And why when external HDD DC, VS error dlls? I search and I can't find it on cache folders but when external HDD connected this message not appear

Comment: Some packages which are used for vs loads project template or internal tool are stored under download caches. And it seems that you have stored the download cache on the extra HDD. That is the reason. And actually, the document did not point that out. But it is truth that VS needs that download caches under test.

Comment: Actually, the packages for VS2019 and VS2017 are different and you should set them separately. I suggest you use VS2019 download cache and it has most of the VS2017 packages, but for some special projects specific to VS2017 packages, VS2019 cache does not have, it may lead to errors, this may be an unstable factor. If you did not want to download the cache, you should uncheck that option `keep download cache after the installation`.

Comment: If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it:)